# C# operands error

Tags: c#, operand

I am trying to calculate the total for a list in my C# program, I have gotten help from several people in my class and we can't seem to find the problem, my code is,

```
        int totalB = 0;

        Cards.ForEach(delegate(ConsoleApplication1.Program.CreditCard Balance)
        {
            totalB= totalB + Balance;
        });
```

The error is this Error 1   Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.CreditCard'

Any help for this would be much appreciated as I have no idea and neither do the people that tried to help me with this issue

Comment: where is your list? what is credit card? my guess would be `Cards.Sum(x => x.Balance);`

Comment: Try yo use a getter in, or from, your class for the member you want to summarize
Just think about, you won't summarize credit cards but you could want to summarize the balance, so you should have a member in your class like CreditCar.Balance in a raw type.
Use that member to summarize

Comment: Have you overridden the "+" operator on CreditCard? If not then how can you expect to add an int to a class?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you have a class like:

```
partial class CreditCard
{
    public int Balance {get; set;}
}
```

So following what you have, explicitly, you most likely intended:

```
int totalB = 0;

Cards.ForEach(delegate(ConsoleApplication1.Program.CreditCard card)
{
    totalB = totalB + card.Balance;
});
```

This iterates over each item in your `Cards` collection, and adds the value of the `Balance` property to `totalB`. Note I have called the variable `card` in the delegate to further illustrate what is going on - the delegate will be called once for each item in the collection. Inside, you can pick out the `Balance` property and add it to `totalB`.

---

Note you can also do this in a number of other ways:

1. Using LINQ:

   ```
   int totalB = Cards.Sum(card => card.Balance);
   ```
2. Using a lambda expression instead of an explicit delegate:

   ```
   int totalB = 0;

   Cards.Foreach(card => {totalB += card.Balance;});
   ```
3. Using a `foreach` loop:

   ```
   int totalB = 0;

   foreach(CreditCard card in Cards)
       totalB += card.Balance;
   ```

(If you are not familiar with it, the `x += y` is the same as `x = x + y`.)

Comment: +1 for pointing out how to directly change OP's code, but its probably worth noting that the linq foreach is evil (per say)

Comment: well at the moment my class for credit card is this, 
public class CreditCard
        {
            public string ID;
            public string Name;
            public string City;
            public double Limit;
            public double Balance;

as it needs to be defined like that for showing I have an understand ing of the C# programming level we are working through at the momnt

Comment: Just tried it and it works for that, cheers for the help mate.

Answer (score 0):

As far as getting sum of list is concerned. it is as simple as (assuming Cards is a list)

```
 Cards.Sum(x=>x.YourPropertyToSum);
```

**Your Error:**

> The error is this Error 1 Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.CreditCard'

you are trying to add an int with ConsoleApplication1.Program.CreditCard (what is this) which is obviously not a type that can be added to int. Hence the error you are getting.

Comment: @downvoter, if you don't mind may i know the reason

Comment: Probably because your answer is pretty much writing what the 3 comments say

Comment: is there a better way of doing things? i would like to know